# Mostrar mensaje de alerta js con php y dirigir a otra pagina

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy haciendo un signup y login con php y html, lo que quiero hacer es que luego de registrarme si todo es correcto me muestre una alerta de js y luego me dirija al login
pero solo me muestra la alterta o simplemente me dirige al login sin la alerta

```
<?php
//OBTENCIÓN DE DATOS

$nombre = $_POST['Name'];

$apellido = $_POST['Surname'];

$email = $_POST['Email'];

$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$password = $_POST['Password'];


//CONEXIÓN
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'photogall');#CONECTAMOS AL LOCALHOST

//EVALUAMOS SI LA CONEXIÓN ES CORRECTA  NO

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error); 

}

else {

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(`Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Gender`, `Email`, `Password`) #INSERTAMOS DENTRO DE LA TABLA LOS VALORES

VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"); #VALUES = ? : ADQUIERE EL NOMBRE DE CADA COLUMNA

 $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $nombre, $apellido, $gender, $email, $password); #INDICA  EL TIPO DE VARIABLE QUE TIENEN LOS PARÁMETROS, EN ESTE CASO TODAS SON STRING

 sleep(1);//SI TODO ESTA CORRECTO SE RETRASA 1 SEGUNDO

 $stmt->execute();

 $stmt->close();

 $conn->close();

 $mensaje ="Registro exitoso"; //ESTA ES LA ALERTA

 echo "<script> alert('$mensaje');</script>";

 header("Location: http://localhost/PhotoGall/html/login.php");

}

?>
```

Alguien tiene una idea del por qué no me funiona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está un poco liado porque parece que mezclas conceptos de php con javascript.

Lo primero es que si este script lo llamas directamente, necesitas devolver las etiquetas para formar una página web, como mínimo <html> y <body>.

Cuando devuelves el código javascript (el alert), deberás hacerlo dentro de un bloque <script>.

Por último, intentas redireccionar la página con una sentencia **header**, lo cual tiene dos problemas, por un lado esta sentencia se ejecuta en el servidor y envía los encabezados para que se redireccione la página, con lo cual nunca se ejecutaría el **alert** que es código javascript que se ejecuta en el navegador. El segundo problema es que los headers se han de enviar ANTES que cualquier otra cosa, con lo que si tu script devuelve algo (con el echo), el header no funcionaría.

Tal y como lo entiendo yo, te pongo un ejemplo omitiendo todo lo superfluo (lo he indicado con ...) y dejando sólo la parte que nos interesa (tú deberías copiarlo todo claro)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

    ...

    $mensaje ="Registro exitoso"; //ESTA ES LA ALERTA

    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('$mensaje');";
    echo "window.location.href = 'http://localhost/PhotoGall/html/login.php';";
    echo "</script>";
    //header("Location: http://localhost/PhotoGall/html/login.php");  <== QUITAR ESTO

    ...
?>
</body>
</html>
```